# How can I use BaseHTTPRequestHandler to forward(routing) the client's Get request to a local server file like Apache?

Tags: python, httpserver, basehttpserver

Let's say there is a path "D:/test.zip", and I have successfully built a server based on BaseHTTPServer( the server is listening on http://127.0.0.1:6000). Its handler class is like this:

```
class MyBaseHttpHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path=="/test.zip":
            print("fetching test.zip.....")
            .....
```

And now, if I type the url "http://127.0.0.1:6000/test.zip" on my browser, my browser should begin to download this zip file—— just like Apache, where I can designate a directory, and users can then access the directory by entering the "http://host:port/directory".

(I don't know how to override the do_GET method to redirect the request to make the file accessible by the client).

**By the way, I don't want to create a html file to do this, and I also don't want to use SimpleHTTPServer or Flask, Django to do that**, though they may do it well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
class MyBaseHttpHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/test.zip":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/zip')
            self.end_headers()
            with open("D:\\test.zip", 'rb') as f:
                self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

Comment: well, this will work in some cases, but may not the answer I want. I want to implement the function like Apache, where I can designate a directory, and when users type "htto://host:port/directory" on their browser and enter, they can access to the directory ( or files) . I think "access" is not completely equal to "read" or "open"

Comment: @vainquit after reading your edit I think I understand what you need, do you want to essentially re-implement `SimpleHTTPRequestHandler`? What specific issues are you encountering with this?

Comment: yes, yes, perhaps that's what I want. Actually, my client (Android Studio, Java) uses a "DonwloadManager" class, which can download a file from an url (but I don't know how it works). So I need to make files on my server accessible, and provide the downloadable files urls to client,  instead of writing bytes to wfile.